# how can xml view can be place on a image having text box and button?

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <!-- Email Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Email input text -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <!-- Password Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" />

    <!-- Password input text -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Login button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am very infant to programming so please help me

Comment: You need buttons,edittext's on the image as screen bg..??

Comment: Did you require to put some thing on Image view ex: Button on Image View?

Comment: can you provide more detail?

Comment: suppose i have button image as background i require to put button on it

Comment: Question needs more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your concern try like this ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

   <!--  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/talktransparent" /> -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/talk_image"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_not_available"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/talk_image"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_new"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/talk_image"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```